# Connecting iisexpress to an azure sql db which is security enabled

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

I created an azure sql database and started developing my web app. From Visual Studio I could debug using iisexpress and it would happily connect.  But now I have turned on the "Security Enabled" feature (to require encrypted connections), the connection from iisexpress times out.

I edited the connection strings in the azure portal and the actual azure web app works fine, its just debugging with iisexpress that is broken. I've copied those exact connection strings into my web.debug.config.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to change the connection string anymore if you set the "Security Enabled Access" to "Required". The only reason to use the security enabled connection string (the ones which looks like: .database.**secure**.windows.net) is if you have down level client. Only .NET 4.0 and below will require it. 4.5 will just work fine.

Please note, the security enabled connection string is not related to encryption. you need this feature if you want Auditing and Dynamic Data Masking.

Thanks,
Tomer - MSFT.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Tomer. I've turned "Security Enabled" off and reset the connection strings - it is working fine now.